# multi client one server architecture with handler in android

Tags: android, multithreading

hi mate i have one thread S and n thread C .
C send request to S ,using sendMessage(msg) on Handler of S.
Every client C1...CN have a private handler.
S receive message on his handler, elaborate the request and want to send the response with sendMessage(risp) on the private handler of specified client. But How can he know what is the handler where C will wait response ? Client C can insert in the request message a refer to his handler where receive response ?

Comment: my server is a simple thread that elaborate the msg of client and send him response

Comment: how can accept an answer of my question ? i m newbie to the forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending your message set its `replyTo` field:

```
msgYouSend.replyTo = new Messenger(yourHandler);
```

Then you can reply like this:

```
msgYouReceived.replyTo.send(yourReplyMessage)
```

See `replyTo` doc at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html

Comment: msgYouSend is the messageof client  and msgYourReceived is the message of server?

Comment: @dario frongi  msgYouSend you are preparing on client side and send to server. On server you have it as msgYouReceived

Comment: when i create my response message called in your example "yourReplyMessage" what handler have i to use in the constructor ? its ok Message yourReplyMessage=requestHandler.obtainMessage(); ? or i have to create it in othermethod ?

Comment: Message yourReplyMessage=new Message();
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putParcelable(keyStringResponse, risp);
yourReplyMessage.setData(b);
try {
      msgYouReceived.replyTo.send(yourReplyMessage);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
      
     }                                                                     its ok ?

Comment: see my answer , please tell me if its ok

Answer (score 0):

```
Message yourReplyMessage=new Message(); 
Bundle b=new Bundle();
 b.putParcelable(keyStringResponse, risp); 
yourReplyMessage.setData(b);
 try { msgYouReceived.replyTo.send(yourReplyMessage);
 } catch (RemoteException e) { }
```

its my solution... do you think that is ok ?